# Wordpress map subdomain to url

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, apache2, subdomain

i would like to have one wordpress site with the following concept:

*www.example.com* should be the root domain
*blog.example.com* should be mapped to *www.example.com/blog*

But when *blog.example.com* should not be redirected to *www.example.com/blog*

I run it on a self-administred apache2 server with mod_rewrite

So how to realise it?

Greetings,
Steven